# How to show Google reviews on my website properly

Tags: seo, google, technical-seo, google-api

Google offers data like photos or up to 5 reviews via their [Places API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/overview).

I just want to know, if I can use this data on my website without SEO penalization...

- Do I need include source of that data somewhere (under images or under reviews)?
- What will be the impact of SEO? If I include exact review text, Google will not consider this as duplicate content?
- Can I mark somehow with SEO tags (`data-nosnippet` or `<!--googleoff: index-->`), that review/images is not unique content of my website but it's from google?

Comment: I expect this is a non-issue. Google loves Google so wont penaluse you for using it.  Simolarly the "duplicate content penalty" is largely a myth.